# Neural networks for correlated time series prediction

Tags: matlab, math, neural-network

I can find a lot of tutorials on time series prediction using NN ( http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/neural-network-prediction/neural-network-training.html )

But my problem is slightly different. I have N correlated signals or time series:

```
x1={x1(t-m) ... x1(t)}, x2={x2(t-m) ... x2(t)}, ... ,xN={xN(t-m) ... xN(t)}
```

All signals are correlated in some degree to one another and my objective is to predict `x1(t+1), x2(t+1) ... xN(t+1)`

For a single time series we have the solution from the link above which is straight forward: you train a NN which has as input `x1(t-m) ... x1(t-1)` and the desired output is `x1(t)`.

When you have multiple signals you could build one NN for each signal but you would lose information regarding the correlation of the signals.

Is it possible to use on NN which has as inputs all the signals `x1 x2 ... xN` for a time window and the desired output would be `x1(t) x2(t) ... xN(t)`? Will this take advantage of the correlation between the signals?

Comment: I avoided this problem by using a bayesian prediction for training.  The time series is a natural product of efficiency where processes are given elevated priority for forking based on proximity to the mean

Comment: What you are saying is possible, but it will be difficult - what you are addressing is almost like speaker recognition. You have correlated signals (speakers) who each record their speech into training. The whole point of NN is to be able to distinguish one speaker from another - in which case you transform your time domain signal into some other domain (something like MFCC is used usually). So in your case, what are you intending to achieve by putting all the correlated signals through the same NN training?

Comment: @GameOfThrows I understand your point. The thing was that I didn't found a way to extract features from my signals (my signals are CPU metrics like cache L1,l2,L3 misses and hits, branch prediction hit or miss, instructions prefetchers miss predictions etc ). I abandoned the project but I don't mind arguing about a way to do this :) So the aim of the project was to predict application behavior on a CPU based on known behavior from some well known benchmarks. But we can talk about the general problem, multivariate time series prediction. What about the newish RNNs or CNNs ?

Comment: @SkyLeach did you use bayesian networks for multivariate time series or for univariate time series ?